# How to modify an image a user sends in Discord using Python?

Tags: python, image, bots, discord

I'm trying to make a discord command that uses the image a user sends and overlays it with a pre-defined image. I just do not know how to make it work.

My command is called "burninate" and I am trying to overlay a fire image on top of the image a user posts, but I do not know how to correctly make the bot use the image a user provides. I tried message.attachments and have received a name error, saying "message" is not defined anywhere in my code, when clearly my other commands using it work.

Here is my horribly broken python code... I am hoping for a fix that does not require me to edit the entire block.

```
@client.command(name='burninate',
            description="Post a static image to burn!",)
async def burninate():
    burnfile=r"C:\Users\Username\Pictures\fire.png"
    providedimage = Image.open (message.attachments)
    fire = Image.open (burnfile)
    burninate = Image.new("RGBA", providedimage.size)
    burninate = Image.alpha_composite(burninate, fire)
    burninate.save("burninate.png")
    await client.send_file(message.channel, "burninate.png")
```

I am using asyncio. I will provide a block of code that I made that does work. although it does not use input from the user.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def morph(ctx):
    folderbase=r"C:\Users\username\Pictures\Cosmic\Babies+Markings\Loga\Base"
    foldermarks=r"C:\Users\username\Pictures\Cosmic\Babies+Markings\Loga\Markings"
    foldereyes=r"C:\Users\username\Pictures\Cosmic\Babies+Markings\Loga\Eyes"
    shading=r"C:\Users\username\Pictures\Cosmic\Babies+Markings\Loga\Shading\Lineart.png"
    a=random.choice(os.listdir(folderbase))
    a2=random.choice(os.listdir(foldereyes))
    a3=random.choice(os.listdir(foldermarks))
    #os.open(a, os.O_RDWR)
    file1 = folderbase+'\\'+a
    file2 = foldereyes+'\\'+a2
    file3 = foldermarks+'\\'+a3
    file4 = shading
    im1 = Image.open(file1)
    im2 = Image.open(file2)
    im3 = Image.open(file3)
    shade = Image.open(file4)
    final2 = Image.new("RGBA", im1.size)
    final2 = Image.alpha_composite(final2, im2)
    final2 = Image.alpha_composite(final2, im1)
    final2 = Image.alpha_composite(final2, im3)
    final2 = Image.alpha_composite(final2, shade)
    final2.save("morph.png")
    await client.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "morph.png")
```

This one just layers four images creating a random alien dinosaur

Comment: Should message be passed into your burninate command as an argument?

Comment: Some information that would be really useful is: what discord client library are you using? Also, you mention that you have other commands that do work - can you include them in the question for comparison?

Comment: I tried that and I got a MissingRequiredArgument error, saying that message is an argument that is missing. Forgive me for being so clueless. I started this bot yesterday.

Comment: Everyone started off clueless! :)

Comment: I am also using asyncio. One command i made that works does not require user input to make the image... it just combines layers.. I can't post it as a comment because it's a long bock of code

Comment: You're using asyncio, but that won't define the @client.command decorator - where are you importing that from? Anyway, the extra code you posted looks like it has a hint.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the command that doesn't work and the one that does is that in the working one you specify `pass_context=true` in the command decorator. That tells whatever framework you're using to pass a context object into the command function - it's the `ctx` argument for `morph`, and from the code I can see that it has a `.message` attribute.

You should change the `burninate` function so that it looks like this:

```
@client.command(name='burninate',
        description="Post a static image to burn!",
        pass_context=True)
async def burninate(ctx):
    burnfile=r"C:\Users\Username\Pictures\fire.png"
    providedimage = Image.open (ctx.message.attachments)
    fire = Image.open (burnfile)
    burninate = Image.new("RGBA", providedimage.size)
    burninate = Image.alpha_composite(burninate, fire)
    burninate.save("burninate.png")
    await client.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "burninate.png")
```

This changes the places where you're using `message` in the function body to use `ctx.message`. That should get rid of the '"message" not defined' error.

Comment: I tried this code and I get an Attribute error. it says `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Ok, I was just adapting the code you provided to give it access to the message object, this is a different problem. It sounds like message.attachments is a list, but I can't tell what the elements are. I'd add a print(ctx.message.attachments) so you can see what they are and try running the command again.

Comment: I started over with a simple code and I realized that if I put `message.<anything>` anywhere in parentheses I WILL get a name error saying `name 'message' is not defined` the difference between my morph code and my burninate code is that there is no `message` in the main block of code for the morph command. only when the file gets sent.

Am I missing an import? Here's what i currently import:

`import discord`
`import random`
`import asyncio`
`import aiohttp`
`import os`
`from discord import Game`
`from discord.ext.commands import Bot`
`from PIL import Image`

Comment: Right - message is passed into your `morph` code as an attribute of the `ctx` object. You can see that morph uses `ctx.message` on the last line. So to be able to use it in `burninate` you need to set `pass_context=True` in the function decorator (the `@client.command` call), and then add a `ctx` parameter to `burninate`. Then instead of using `message.<anything>` in burninate, you need to use `ctx.message.<whatever>`. Or you could add `message = ctx.message` at the start of the function, then just use message normally.